# Using same jQuery function to control multiple instances on same page

Tags: jquery, function

I have two different divs on the same page that need to scroll content in exactly the same way. My current code works well enough, however there is probably a more optimal way to achieve this. I just don't how to tell jQuery to use #move-1 for #container-1 and #move-2 for #container-2 in the same function. Can anyone tell me how to do so?

HTML

```
<div id="container-1" class="container">
    <div class="item item-1">container 1 - item 1</div>
    <div class="item item-2">container 1 - item 2</div>
    <div class="item item-3">container 1 - item 3</div>
</div>
    <button id="move-1">Move item in container 1</button>
<div id="container-2" class="container">
    <div class="item item-1">container 2 - item 1</div>
    <div class="item item-2">container 2 - item 2</div>
    <div class="item item-3">container 2 - item 3</div>
</div>
    <button id="move-2">Move item in container 2</button>
```

jQuery

```
$( "#move-1" ).click(function() 
    {
        $( "#container-1 .item" ).animate({ "top": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
    });

$( "#move-2" ).click(function() 
    {
        $( "#container-2 .item" ).animate({ "top": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
    });
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: arial, sans;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 190px;
    height: 90px;
    color: #000;
    overflow: auto;
}

.item-1 {
    top: 0px;
}

.item-2 {
    top: 200px;
}

.item-3 {
    top: 400px;
}

button {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c33qkmav/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ID of the clicked element and get the number

```
$('[id^="move-"]').on('click', function()  {
    var id = this.id.split('-').pop();
    $('#container-' + id + ' .item').animate({ "top": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c33qkmav/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Really simply, if your HTML is the same throughout you can use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous element and then find the children within:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   $(this).prev().find('.item').animate({ "top": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c33qkmav/5/)